# Multiple Heights iOS keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS keyboard extension. I want the keyboard to have multiple heights. Up to four different heights depending on the current task.
The heights are numerous depending on the device family i.e iPhone, iPhonePlus and iPads.

I start by declaring a mainHeightConstraint like so

```
var mainHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Then I set the height based on the device like so

```
 func checkDeviceSize() {
    if device.isOneOf(iphoneSeries) {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.width {
            print("iPhone Potrait")
            AConstant = 280
            BConstant = 400
            CConstant = 320
            DConstant = self.view.frame.height
        } else {
            print("iPhone Landscape")
            AConstant = 220
            BConstant = 340
            CConstant = 240
            DConstant = self.view.frame.height
        }

    } else if device.isOneOf(iphonePlusSeries) {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.width {
            print("regular height iphonePlus potrait")
            AConstant = 280
            BConstant = 380
            CConstant = 300
            DConstant = self.view.frame.height
        } else {
            print("regular width iphonePlus landscape")
            AConstant = 220
            BConstant = 320
            CConstant = 300
            DConstant = self.view.frame.height
        }

    } else if device.isOneOf(ipadSeries) {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.width {
            print("regular height ipad potrait")
            AConstant = 280
            BConstant = 460
            CConstant = 280
            DConstant = 500
        } else {
            print("regular height ipad landscape")
            AConstant = 360
            BConstant = 440
            CConstant = 360
            DConstant = 500
        }
    }
}
```

and set the constraint like so

```
func initialHeight() {
    self.mainHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: self.mainConstant)
    self.mainHeightConstraint!.priority = 1000
    self.view.addConstraint(self.mainHeightConstraint!)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

when the device is rotated, I change the heights like so

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (void) in
        self.mainHeightConstraint?.isActive = false
        self.checkDeviceSize()
        let currentHeight = (groupDefaults?.string(forKey: "CurrentHeight"))! as String
        print("\(currentHeight)")
        switch currentHeight {
        case NORMAL_HEIGHT:
            self.normalHeight()
        case EXTENDED_HEIGHT:
            self.extendedHeight()
        case MEDIUM_HEIGHT:
            self.mediumHeight()
        case FULL_HEIGHT:
            self.fullHeight()
        default: break
        }
        self.initialHeight()
        self.style()
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

which calls any of these depending on what is needed.

```
func extendedHeight() {
    print("Extended Height Set")
    self.view.removeConstraint(mainHeightConstraint!)
    groupDefaults?.set(EXTENDED_HEIGHT, forKey: CURRENT_HEIGHT)
    currentHeightMode = 3
    mainConstant = BConstant
    self.carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(0)
    initialHeight()
}

func normalHeight() {
    print("Normal Height Set")
    self.view.removeConstraint(mainHeightConstraint!)
    groupDefaults?.set(NORMAL_HEIGHT, forKey: CURRENT_HEIGHT)
    currentHeightMode = 1
    mainConstant = AConstant
    self.carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(35)
    initialHeight()
}

func mediumHeight() {
    print("Medium Height Set")
    self.view.removeConstraint(mainHeightConstraint!)
    groupDefaults?.set(MEDIUM_HEIGHT, forKey: CURRENT_HEIGHT)
    currentHeightMode = 2
    mainConstant = CConstant
    self.carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(0)
    initialHeight()

}

func fullHeight() {
    print("Full Height Set")
    self.view.removeConstraint(mainHeightConstraint!)
    groupDefaults?.set(FULL_HEIGHT, forKey: CURRENT_HEIGHT)
    currentHeightMode = 4
    mainConstant = DConstant
    self.carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(0)
    initialHeight()
}
```

Everything works well when the view is loaded. The heights change to the various levels. My issue is when I rotate. For example when I rotate to landscape, everything works well but when I rotate back the height of the keyboard remains at the landscape height and all the different heights are also broken and remain at the landscape height.

I do get this on the log

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmx9.png)

which tells me that both the landscape height I am leaving 220 and the portrait height I am going to 280 are both active and xcode chooses to break the portrait height. How do I remove the landscape height. I tried calling

```
self.view.removeConstraint(mainHeightConstraint!)
```

when viewWillTransition is called but no dice.